# Set cell size in Heat Map. Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to set the height/width of a cell in a heat map?

To have for example this one from 0.4 to 2 (xAxis):

http://jsfiddle.net/xy79ugrd/

```
data: [{x: 0.4, y:0, value: 10, ...},
```

Answer (score 0):

In case when you have categories on the xAxis, each value (x) needs to be equal number. When you use 0.4, it is incorrect.

Comment: I don't have categories on xAxis. xAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 9
        },

Comment: Indeed, but in case when others values are equal, and suddnely you ise 0.4, how it should be printed? Obivously you can control tickInterval on xAxis and set colsize (like here: http://jsfiddle.net/xy79ugrd/) but it will be never justify, because you have different ranges.

Comment: No you cant, because data needs to be frequent to have the same cols.

Comment: frequent in all the rows do you mean? Wouldnt it create empty cols for that cases?

Comment: If you need empty cols, you need to set null value per points. TIt is default behaviour so you can develop own.

Answer (score 0):

"I am trying to reproduce this with highcharts: wlcg-sam-atlas.cern.ch/dashboard/request.py/… Any chance to do it?"

I see two options:

1) use the heatmap, but rather than trying to make different sized cells, you need to use the smallest unit as your cell size, and there will be repeated values. This is the appropriate way to use a heatmap as opposed to altering the size of each cell.

2) instead of a heatmap, use a stacked bar. This will require a lot of series which could impact performance at some point. A floating bar could work as well and wouldn't require separate series for each cell.

Comment: Option 1) the "repeated" values wouldn't be the same ones, because they would be in a different time, and depending on the time the user has to go to one place or another

Comment: but if your cell is wider, it's covering a larger time frame...  I guess we'd need to know the end goal and the use of the chart

Comment: You are right. Each point represents a test done, when you click, you go to the details, for that, its necessary the date when it was done. Longer ones represents no more tests done, it expires in one hour (white spaces). This is a better example: http://tinyurl.com/kdetjay

Comment: I think the floating bar option will be the way to go in that case